# Importing CSV infile

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Ive tried to follow examples of how to import a csv infile with no luck.  I have the following CSV-

[image]

And from what I understand, I need to set up a table in Workbench, with column names that match the CSV columns.  I've done this:

[image]

Using this code-

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Sam/Desktop/Eviction_Notices_2012to2017_AddressthruZip.csv' INTO TABLE evictions.test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(Address, City, State, Zip);
```

I've had varying degrees of success.   Right now, it only imports first 99 rows even though there is no limit specified.

Also, is there a way to copy your column names from excel easily into the alter table window, rather than creating each column name manually?

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: have you checked the 99th record manually to lookout for errors?

Comment: yes. it looks no different than the other records.

Comment: There is no way to set up a table to look like an excel spreadsheet. Although you could just use excel formulas to write up your `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` statement so you don't have to write so much code (or click so many buttons in your UI). Are you going over the allotted size for your field in your load (Like trying to load 120 characters into a VARCHAR(110))?